# Array is not accessible outside of Casper repeat function

Tags: javascript, casperjs

My goal is to get each job link of a job site, go to each Job detail page by following Job link, download and save the detail in html through CASPERJS.
As id of each Job link change each time we back & forth between job link and job detail page, I need to get all the Job id each time under casper.repeat . But NoOfLink array is become empty outside of repeat function [I comment that part in code]. What is the problem?

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var noOfRecordsToLoop = 0;
var TotalNoofNullElement = 0;
var NoOfLink = [];

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.echo('\nStart loding site......');

//---------------------------------------------Load and Scroll the site---------------------------------------//

casper.start('https://........../...../.......Careers/');

casper.wait(10000, function () {
    //---------Total no of Job posting------//

    var noOfRecords = this.fetchText(x('//*[@id="...........................jobProfile......"]'));
    noOfRecordsToLoop = noOfRecords.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
    var totalNoOfPage = Math.ceil(parseInt(noOfRecords) / 50);

    casper.echo('\nStart scrolling site......');

    casper.repeat(totalNoOfPage, function () {
        this.scrollToBottom(); //-----------------------Scroll down
        casper.wait(10000, function () {})
    })

})

//------------------------------------------------Load and Scroll the site---------------------------------------//


casper.then(function () {
    //-----------------------------------------Get all the link elements  --------------------------//

    var countForLink = 0;
    var numTimesForRpt = noOfRecordsToLoop;
    var numTimes = noOfRecordsToLoop;

    casper.repeat(numTimesForRpt, function () {

        RetElement = this.evaluate(function () {
            var startingRow = '//*[contains(@id, "...-uid-")]'
                var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath(startingRow).getAttribute('id');
            return element;
        });

        var count = RetElement.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

        casper.repeat(numTimes, function () {
            var MatchElements = this.evaluate(function (count) {
                    var xp = '//*[contains(@id, "...-uid-' + count + '")]'
                        var element = __utils__.getElementByXPath(xp).getAttribute('id');
                    return element;
                }, count++);

            if (!MatchElements) {
                TotalNoofNullElement = TotalNoofNullElement + 1
            } else {
                NoOfLink.push(MatchElements);
            }

            //**Here array elements are accessible**
            for (var k = 0; k < NoOfLink.length; k++) {
                this.echo(NoOfLink[k]);
            }

        });

        //**But here array elements are not accessible outside of repeat** function
        this.echo("Size of array is" + NoOfLink.length);

        for (var q = 0; q < NoOfLink.length; q++) {
            this.echo(NoOfLink[q]);
        }

        //-----------------------------------------Get all the link elements----------------------------//

        //------------------------------------Go to the Job Detail Page Extract HTML and Save---------------------------//

        this.echo("\n Inside repeat to Generate HTML");
        var num = NoOfLink[countForLink];
        this.echo("\nLink id is " + NoOfLink[countForLink]);
        num = parseInt(num.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
        this.echo("\nNum is " + num);

        //-----------------Click to go to the Job Detail Page------------------//

        casper.thenClick(x('//*[@id="..-uid-' + num + '"]/div/div'));

        casper.wait(5000, function getJobDetail() {

            var content = this.getElementInfo(x(".//*[contains(@id,'......t-uid-')]")).html;
            var divStart = '<div id="extrdHtml">'
                var divEnd = '</div>'
                var body = divStart + content + divEnd

                this.echo("\nContent of Job detail :" + body);

            var fs = require('fs');

            fs.write('extractedJob' + NoOfLink[countForLink] + '.html', body, 'w');

            this.echo("\nFile saved");

            //------------------------------------Go to the Job Detail Page Extract HTML and Save---------------------------//

        }); //casper.wait

        casper.back();

        casper.wait(5000);

        countForLink++

    }); //casper.repeat

}); //casper.then

//-------------------------------------------Get all the link elements------------------------------//

casper.run();
```

There are two repeat loops.

1. `casper.repeat(numTimesForRpt, function () {` - This is main outer loop , where the 2nd loop resides.
2. `casper.repeat(numTimes, function ()` – Where I am getting the link and populating `NoOfLink` array. I am trying to get the array element value outside of this 2nd loop(within main outer loop) but it is not working.

Comment: Thanks for your reply….there are two repeat loop
   1. casper.repeat(numTimesForRpt, function () { - This is main outer loop , whiten this 2nd loop is resides.
   2. casper.repeat(numTimes, function () – Where I am getting the link and populating NoOfLink array. I am trying to get the array element value outside of this 2nd loop(within main outer loop) but it is not working.
I am not able to understand whether it is somehow limitation, bug or a scope problem, any other way we can fix it.
Please let me know if you need any other information.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `then*` and `wait*` functions are asynchronous step functions. If you call them, you're scheduling a step that is executed at the end of the current step. `casper.repeat()` is a function that [uses `casper.then()`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L1456) and is therefore also asynchronous. Every synchronous code that comes after `casper.repeat()` will be executed *before* the contents of the `repeat` callback.

You have two options:

1. Wrap everything that comes after `casper.repeat()` in a `casper.then()` to make it asynchronous or
2. Use a normal synchronous loop instead of `repeat`, if the callback of `repeat` doesn't need to be evaluated asynchronously **like in your case**.

By the way, you can oftentimes reduce your code a bit by utilizing the helper functions that CasperJS provides. For example, you don't need to use `evaluate()` only to get the id attributes of some elements by XPath. You can do that with [`casper.getElementsAttribute()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsattribute).

Example:

```
var count = RetElement.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

for(var i = count; i < (numTimes + count); i++) {
    var MatchElements = this.getElementsAttribute(x('//*[contains(@id, "...-uid-' + i + '")]'), 'id');

    if (!MatchElements) {
        TotalNoofNullElement = TotalNoofNullElement + 1
    } else {
        NoOfLink.push(MatchElements);
    }

    //**Here array elements are accessible**
    for (var k = 0; k < NoOfLink.length; k++) {
        this.echo(NoOfLink[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have taken 2nd approach.It is working now as expected.Thank you for your explanation and suggestion.